# How parse array JSON file?

Tags: angularjs

media.json :

```
[{"id": 1, "title": "blabla"},{"id": 2, "title": "blabla"}]
```

service.js

```
.factory('media', function($http, $log, $q){
return{
    getMedia: function(){
        console.log('getMedias');
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('js/media.json')
        .success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function(msg, code){
            deferred.reject(msg);
            $log.error(msg,code)
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

});

I'm trying to make a service via $http.get and $q but an error appears : `Unexpected token`

(This file should be a web service in final version)

what is the best practice to use ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add few more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass an array via http GET put it inside an object ..

```
var obj={
  array:[{"id": 1, "title": "blabla"},{"id": 2, "title": "blabla"}]
}
```

and then send this object.

[Reference](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3121#issuecomment-20453196)